# getting attribute value from Div tag through jSoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have a Div tag as below

```
<div id="eventTTL" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 900;" eventTTL="4583476000">5 days 07:14:41</div>
```

How do i get the value of eventTTL? I want to display the value of eventTTL ie:) "4583476000".

Comment: What part do you need help with? Getting the `div` or getting the `eventTTL` attribute from that element? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: I got the Div. I want to get eventTTL from Div?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Element div = doc.getElementById("eventTTL");
String attr = div.attr("eventTTL");
System.out.println(attr);
```

More info at: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Answer (score 2):

In case if your DIV has no Id:

```
Element div = doc.select("div[eventTTL]").first();
System.out.println(div.attr("eventTTL"));
```