# How to access an element using Jsoup in Android

Tags: android, html, jsoup

!I need to extract this element in android - How do i do that using Jsoup...please help
I have tried using
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa29b.jpg)

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><tbody><tr><td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;"><div class="gwt-Tree" style="position: relative;" role="tree"><div tabindex="0" style="font-size: 0px; position: absolute; outline: 0px none; z-index: -1; left: 39px; top: 28px; width: 66px; height: 20px;" hidefocus="true" role="treeitem" aria-activedescendant="gwt-uid-9"> … </div><div style="padding: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"><table style="white-space: nowrap;"><tbody><tr><td style="vertical-align: middle;"> … </td><td style="vertical-align: middle;">**<div id="gwt-uid-8" class="gwt-TreeItem" style="display: inline;" role="treeitem">
```

Sites - I Need to extract this element

```
  </div>**</td></tr></tbody></table><div style="white-space: nowrap;"> … </div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table>

Element Stats = document.select("div > td").first();
Elements nodeBlogStats = Stats.select("div[id = gwt-uid-8]");
```

Comment: try Stats.select("div #gwt-uid-8"); instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230660/getting-attribute-value-from-div-tag-through-jsoup

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
String Stats= document.select("div #gwt-uid-8").attr("style");
```