# How to get url from iterator?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

How get url from iterator, I'm using jsoup.   [image]

I tried to do `urls.add(ite.next().parentNode().attributes().asList().get(0).toString());` but the value is not what need.

Comment: How are you getting this iterator? What is it iterating over? `asList()` looks questionable to me; you should be getting the attribute by name, not by its position. What if there was a tag like `<a title="Yo" href="http://whatever"></a>`?

Comment: what value you are getting?

Comment: David Conrad,Iterator<Element> ite = table.select("FONT[style=FONT-SIZE: 10pt]").iterator(); get iterator. I know that asList() was incorrectly

Comment: Vishrant, for example "my_url.htm"

Comment: I solved problem: ite.next().parentNode().attributes().html().toString();

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading this documentation on how to extract attribute values from elements:
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

There's also this example from stack overflow itself:
[getting attribute value from Div tag through jSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230660/getting-attribute-value-from-div-tag-through-jsoup)

Something like this should resolve your problem:

```
Element link = doc.getElementById("yourlinkid");
String attr = link.attr("href");
System.out.println(attr);
```

There are different ways to find your link using different selectors.

Comment: I use elements:Element table = doc.select("table[width=90%]").first();
And also need use:Iterator<Element> ite = table.select("FONT[style=FONT-SIZE: 10pt]").iterator();

Comment: this is a useful information but I don't know that get required value

Comment: Check the update, select your link element and gert the attribute from it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the parent node, you should be able to call the attr function.
See the docs: [http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr(java.lang.String)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr%28java.lang.String%29)

Also notice the option to prefix with abs to get the absolute and not the relative path:

```
String url = a.attr("abs:href");
```