# Get key value from an jsoup Elements object in Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I have got an [Elements](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) object created with jsoup:

`Elements webArticles = webPage.select("article[data-name]");`

That's the Elements object resultant:

[Object screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU8Ct.png) (sorry, I am not allowed to add images).

I am trying to get some of the values, e.g., "data-name" and "data-brand" with no success. I am able to get all [x] element values, but I would like to get just the string values.

Sorry if I am not explaining myself properly, I am just starting with Java.

Thanks!!

Comment: "*I am trying to get some of the values, e.g., "data-name" and "data-brand" with no success*" can you show us your attempt? If I understand you correctly you just need to iterate over all selected elements stored in `webArticles`, for instance like `for(Element el : webArticles)` and then get value of attribute you are interested in, like `String attrValue = el.attr("data-name")`. What problems are you facing exactly?

Comment: Solved reading jsoup doc: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html and using ```.attr("data-name")```. Sorry for ask before read.

Comment: @Pshemo, thank you for your comment. I was trying to get the values not using ```.attr()``` (basically, not reading the documentation).

Comment: If that is the case than am I correctly assuming that main question was "*how to get value of attribute?*"? If yes then since it is also already answered at [getting attribute value from Div tag through jSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9230660) I will mark your question as duplicate of that one. If I am mistaken please let me know.